# When i run the test for the R package i got this error object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Tags: r, testthat

**This is my linreg function that calculates the multiple regression and returns RC object.**

This function takes a formula and data frame as input and do some regression analysis and then return an RC type of object.
I'm creating the RC object at the end of calculations and then return of a new object of RC.

```
  
  data_name <- deparse(substitute(data))

  X <- model.matrix(formula, data)

  y_col <- data[all.vars(formula)[1]]
  y <- as.matrix(y_col)
 
  X[is.na(X)] <- 0
  
  transpose_X <- t(X)
  
  X_tranp_inversion <- solve(transpose_X %*% X)

  beta_hat <- X_tranp_inversion %*% (transpose_X %*% y)
  
  fitted_value_y_hat <- X %*% beta_hat
  
  residuals <-  y- fitted_value_y_hat
  
  degree_freedom <- nrow(X) - ncol(X)
  
  variance_sqr <- (t(residuals) %*% residuals) / degree_freedom
  
  variance_beta <- as.vector(variance_sqr) * diag(X_tranp_inversion)
  parameters <- diag(X_tranp_inversion)
  parameters_names <- names(parameters)
  
  t_value <- NA
    
  t_value <- beta_hat/ sqrt(variance_beta)
    
  p_value <- 2*pt(-abs(t_value),degree_freedom)
  
  linreg <- setRefClass("linreg",
                        fields = list(name = "character",
                                      data = "data.frame",
                                      parameters = "numeric",
                                      parameters_names = "character",
                                      residuals = "vector",
                                      predicted_y = "vector",
                                      coefficent = "vector")
                        )
                        
  
  linreg$methods(show = function(){
    cat("Call:\n")
    cat(paste0(.self$name,"\n"))
    cat("Coefficients:\n")
    names(.self$parameters) <- .self$parameters_names
    print(.self$parameters)
    
  })
  
  linreg$methods(initialize = function(name = "",
                                       formula_name = "",
                                       data_name = "",
                                       dataframe,
                                       param,
                                       param_names,
                                       resid,
                                       pred_y){
    #dataframe_name <- deparse(substitute(dataframe))
    .self$data <<- dataframe
    formula_vars <- as.character(formula_name)
    .self$name <<- paste0("linreg(formula = ",
                          formula_vars[2],
                          formula_vars[1],
                          formula_vars[3],
                          ", data = ",
                          data_name ,")\n")
    .self$parameters <<- param
    .self$parameters_names <<- param_names 
     names(.self$parameters) <-  parameters_names
    .self$coefficent <<- .self$parameters
    .self$residuals <<- as.vector(resid)
    .self$predicted_y <<- as.vector(pred_y)
    .self$show()
    
  })
  
  linreg$methods(plot = function(){
    ggplot2::qplot(Sepal.Length,Petal.Length,data = data)
  })
  linreg$methods(summary = function(){
    cat("i'm summary")
  })
  linreg$methods(resid = function(){
    return(.self$residuals)
  })
  linreg$methods(pred = function(){
    return(.self$predicted_y)
  })
  linreg$methods(coef = function(){
    return(coefficent)
  })
  
  
  return(linreg$new(formula_name = formula,
                    data_name = data_name,
                    dataframe = data,
                    param = parameters,
                    param_names = parameters_names,
                    resid = residuals,
                    pred_y = fitted_value_y_hat))
}
```

**Below are the test cases that I run, some else wrote these but I have to pass those**

```
context("linreg")

data("iris")

Polygon <- setRefClass("Polygon", fields = c("sides"))
square <- Polygon$new(sides = 4)
test_that("lenreg rejects errounous input", {
  expect_error(linreg_mod <- linreg$new(formula = Petal.Length~Sepdsal.Width+Sepal.Length, data=iris))
  expect_error(linreg_mod <- linreg$new(formula = Petal.Length~Sepdsal.Width+Sepal.Length, data=irfsfdis))
})


test_that("class is correct", {
  linreg_mod <- linreg$new(Petal.Length~Sepal.Width+Sepal.Length, data=iris)
  
  expect_true(class(linreg_mod)[1] == "linreg")
})

test_that("print() method works", {
  linreg_mod <- linreg$new(Petal.Length~Sepal.Width+Sepal.Length, data=iris)
  
  expect_output(linreg_mod$print(),"linreg\\(formula = Petal\\.Length ~ Sepal\\.Width \\+ Sepal\\.Length, data = iris\\)")
  expect_output(linreg_mod$print(),"( )*\\(Intercept\\)( )*Sepal\\.Width( )*Sepal\\.Length")
})

test_that("pred() method works", {
  linreg_mod <- linreg$new(Petal.Length~Sepal.Width+Sepal.Length, data=iris)
  
  expect_equal(round(unname(linreg_mod$pred()[c(1,5,7)]),2), c(1.85, 1.53, 1.09))    
})

test_that("resid() method works", {
  linreg_mod <- linreg$new(Petal.Length~Sepal.Width+Sepal.Length, data=iris)
  
  expect_equal(round(unname(linreg_mod$resid()[c(7,13,27)]),2), c(0.31, -0.58, -0.20))
})

test_that("coef() method works", {
  linreg_mod <- linreg$new(Petal.Length~Sepal.Width+Sepal.Length, data=iris)
  
  expect_true(all(round(unname(linreg_mod$coef()),2) %in% c(-2.52, -1.34, 1.78)))
})


test_that("summary() method works", {
  linreg_mod <- linreg$new(Petal.Length~Sepal.Width+Sepal.Length, data=iris)
  
  expect_output(linreg_mod$summary(), "\\(Intercept\\)( )*-2.5[0-9]*( )*0.5[0-9]*( )*-4.4[0-9]*( )*.*( )*\\*\\*\\*")  
  expect_output(linreg_mod$summary(), "Sepal.Width( )*-1.3[0-9]*( )*0.1[0-9]*( )*-10.9[0-9]*( )*.*( )*\\*\\*\\*")
  expect_output(linreg_mod$summary(), "Sepal.Length( )*1.7[0-9]*( )*0.0[0-9]*( )*27.5[0-9]*( )*.*( )*\\*\\*\\*")
  expect_output(linreg_mod$summary(), "Residual standard error: 0.6[0-9]* on 147 degrees of freedom")
})
```

*test_lab4.R:14: error: class is correct
object of type 'closure' is not subsettable*

**I'm getting the above error.**

Comment: To help others help you, please provide a [Minimal Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/13513328) instead of your whole code

Comment: linreg(formula = Petal.Length~Species,data = iris).
You have run this function to check the output of linreg function.

Comment: For the test to run you have to create new package and Put the first block of code in new R file and save it. Then you have to run usethis::use_testthat() this in console of R studio. Then add  the second block of the code on testthat folder.